# How can I create custom collision for this mesh

Tags: mesh, collision

I don't know how to create custom collision for this helmet I was created in blender.I just only want to create collision on surface of this mesh .

[image]

[Here is my blender FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAMIKr5CZ6-A9wd2dJyV1Ys9zUtTd4Nb/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Ok . I got it . Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

select the faces you want to collide in the edit mode and shift D to duplicate those faces then with those faces selected click the right mouse button and select separate => selection, make those faces into a separate object, then select this object go to physic tab toggle collision tab, and hide this object in render, you will have a collision proxy for your helmet and if your helmet mesh has too many faces you can add a decimate modifier to lower the faces count as long as it keeps the shape.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It that correct ? https://i.imgur.com/CETd8eF.png

Comment: I did not saw anychange in it . Can you guide me please

Comment: Welcome and thanks for your answer. It might be clearer if you show some screenshots while you talk through the process. There's nothing wrong with what you've posted here, but some may struggle to follow a block of text like this, and we try to focus on high quality answers, that's all. Have a good day :)